# Packages getting installed only in Python 2.7 but not in 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, python-3.5

i'm using pip to install the packages I need: Numpy & Scipy. However, **they only work if I import them using python 2.7**. When I try doing in with 3.5 it seems as if it wasn't installed at all.

I updated pip and got its version `pip 8.0.2 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)` then I tried: `pip3.5 --version` and got:

```
pip 8.0.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-
packages (python 3.5)
```

All I want is that all packages I download, I can use them with Python 3.5. I don't use 2.7 but I don't want to delete it because I read it's not such a good idea.

Can anyone explain me how can I install the packages for them to work on 3.5 and not only in 2.7, please?

Thank you very much in advance for reading :) and useful help.

PS: Im using OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Packages for Python 2 and Python 3 are installed separately, and installing in one version won't make a package available to the other.  `pip` is Python 2, and so it only installs for Python 2; to install packages for Python 3, use `pip3`.

Comment: Perfect!! And thanks for also explaining what the problem was! :)